# Fetch record from table with duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have my table structure like below in desc order

```
sr  group   name    status
4   class11 ghanshyam   Joined
3   class11 ghanshyam   Removed
2   class11 ghanshyam   suspended
1   class11 ghanshyam   joined
```

Now I want to fetch all record in group class11 whose status is Removed.

So my query will be

```
select * from table where group = 'class11' and status='Removed' group by name
```

but now ghanshyam has rejoined group after status removed and we are duplicating entries so it should not count in Removed, same for suspended account.

So how Can I fetch desired row from table

Comment: `sr` is primary key for this table?

Comment: yes sr is primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* from [table] t1

INNER JOIN

( SELECT MAX(sr) AS nsr ,[group] ,[name] FROM [table] GROUP BY [group] ,[name] ) t2

ON t2.nsr = t1.sr
AND t1.status='Removed'
```

Comment: am i using correct query, this is giving correct result when changing status from joined, removede, suspended???

Comment: @praveen86 Yeah.. glad to hear that :) Feel free to upvote the answer too. Also the answer of Desai will do the job. So do appreciate their efforts too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the record in all cases, like this :

```
select * from table where group = 'class11'
```

after doing that you can check the last status if its removed or joined.

Comment: NO I cant do that because I want total count on basis of sql query mysql_num_row() and then I want to do pagination with limit

Comment: praveen, this is somewhat unclear that what exactly you want. Can you please explain that what exact response you're expecting from your query in your case?

Comment: ghanshyam should not come in select * from table where group = 'class11' and status='Removed' group by name query, he should come only for joined status

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM yourTable 
WHERE group = 'class11' AND status ='Removed' 
AND (SELECT MAX(sr) FROM yourTable WHERE group = 'class11' AND status ='Joined') < sr
GROUP BY name`

Hope that this will help you :)
Rest for any clarification, please add comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will get records which have maximum id for `removed`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name t WHERE t.sr IN 
  (SELECT max(t1.sr) FROM tbl_name t1 WHERE `group` = 'class11' GROUP BY t1.`name`) 
  AND t.status = 'Removed'
```

Check thus fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef189a/1